# Pass python argument to shell

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

In the python notebook I would like to pass the temp argument in the first line to the last line, but am not sure how to do that.

```
def grabdata(statefolders, temp, split_by):
    for folder in statefolders:
        sub = folder.split('_')[split_by]
        new_name = sub + '_out.txt'
        !cp {folder}/done/sigdet_output*out temp{new_name}
```

Comment: Your last line would just cause a ```SyntaxError```.
Do you want to do something like ```subprocess.run('cp {folder}/done/sigdet_output*out {temp}{new_name}'.format(folder=folder, temp=temp, new_name=new_name), shell=True)```?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If

```
!cp {folder}/done/sigdet_output*out temp{new_name}
```

is what you would usually execute in your shell, the [command](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html) in Python would be:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(["cp", "{}/done/sigdet_output*out".format(folder), "temp{}".format(new_name)])
```